# How to determine the FIRST set of E in this grammar?

Tags: parsing, grammar

I wonder how to determine the `FIRST` set of E with grammar:

```
E -> XYE | e
X -> x
Y -> y
```

Can anyone give me some direction?

Comment: You forgot the homework tag, and why does it have to be done in java?

Comment: What do you mean by "the First of E"?!

Comment: First(_E_) is the set of terminals that could be present at the start of _E_. These are the terminals you use for state transitions since you'll always hit one of them.

Comment: Indeed. Fixed the wording to make this clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, assuming that you're starting with *E*, then either the first terminal is x via the *E*→*XYE* production (since *X* always produces x) or it is e via the *E*→e production. So First(*E*) = {x,e}.

That seems pretty straightforward...

Answer (score 0):

Treat rules of the form  A ->  ...x... | ...y ....
as two rules  A -> ...x... and  B -> ...y...

Form a set S initially containing rules of form E-> ....

then

```
Set a set P to empty.
Set a set F to empty.
Repeat until S is empty 
  Choose element of S, and call it R
  If R is in P, remove R from S
  Elsif R is of the form  A -> b ... 
    then { add b to F,
           add R to P,
           remove R from S}
  Else (R is the form A -> B ...)
     then  { place all rules of form B -> ... into S
             remove R from S}
End
```

WHen the loop terminates, F contains the tokens which
are the First(F).

This does not take into account empty productions.