# Calculating the first set of a grammar?

Tags: parsing, set, grammar, recursive-descent, ll-grammar

I have this grammar and I have calculate the first sets myself but I'm unsure how to show my working as the method shown to me I found was too confusing but I understand how to get the sets just not how to show my working.

Grammar is as follows:

```
S -> a a E | a E | S b ,
D -> E D d | c c | EPSILON ,
Y -> D E D | d ,
E -> a E D | EPSILON ,
```

my first sets are:

```
first(S) = {a}
first(D) = {a, c, epsilon}
first(Y) = {d, c, a, epsilon}
first(E) = {a, epsilon}
```

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct. `first(D)` includes `d` since both `E` and `D` can be EPSILON.

Comment: yeah think your right mate thanks for that wasn't thinking about if epsilon was chosen

Answer (score 1):

It seems like maybe you don't actually know how to do it. I suggest following one of the hundreds of online descriptions of this algorithm. Here are a few.

[How to determine the FIRST set of E in this grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659126/how-to-determine-the-first-set-of-e-in-this-grammar)

[How to calculate FIRST sets by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633961/how-to-calculate-first-sets-by-hand)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k00FSxfCbfI

Comment: thanks for the comment but I do know how to do it but there is a process I was taught how to do which includes showing how got it step by step